# How to filter custom Big Object fields?

Tags: big-object

Here's my question on custom big object: can we filter a record under big object?. I just want to filter and show an account record based on account name, here we are storing about 300,000 records of some custom object.

Comment: Account is not a BigObject. Can you clarify by *editing* your question how you are using BigObjects in this scenario? Or is your question related to high data volume?

Comment: Agree with you David, for example if it's a custom Order__b big object. Can we search a record based on order number? where I have already stored some 300,000 records?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can perform a SOQL query against a BigObject table. However, there are [very significant limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_querying.htm) as to how you can construct your query.

The true answer to your question is going to ride on how your BigObject is [defined](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_define.htm). That's because the specific fields, and their order, in the BigObject's index defines how you can use standard SOQL against it.

If you're working with a BigObject `Order__b` and it has an `Order_Number__c` field that is the first field in its index, you can query using `WHERE Order_Number__c = :SOME_ORDER_NUMBER`, for example.

If you want to do something more than that, you'd need to use [Async SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/async_query_overview.htm) to filter a dataset into a new custom object that you can then operate upon.

Comment: and I can show the results on visualforce page also right?.

Comment: I can't say as I've ever built a Visualforce page using BigObjects. I don't know if there are limitations there.

Answer (score 0):

As I completed a small project on Big object, I can say this can be done with Index fields. Please take assess which fields you want to filter and take index on those fields, so that you will be able to filter the records in the SOQL query.